# Replace the object type by common data types - Type safety

Tags: c#, object, types, intellisense

I am developping a system that deals with many modules, which all have their own sets of parameters. Each parameter value can be of a common data type (string, int, long, bytes, bool).
For simplicty, a parameter object has been defined as per:

```
public class Parameter : IParameter
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public object Value { get; set; }
    public string ValueType { get; set; }
}
```

Now, note that the parameter Value is declared using the type "object". The problem with that is that we loose the type safety that validates that a type is correct when assigning a value to a variable. Say the "Value" is an "int" and we were to set it to a bool, VS will complain pre and post compilation.

Now I was wondering if I could declare all the variantes of "Value" in this sorts of way:

```
public int IIntInterface.Value { get; set; }
public string IStringInterface.Value { get; set; }
public bool IBoolInterface.Value { get; set; }
```

But then, when assigning a number/string to the property "Value", "ValueType" is first checked to validate the value so that an error is flagged when the wrong type is used for that parameter?

Essentially, I am trying to get type safety support for the "object" type :-)

------------- Update ------------
I tried to keep it simple, but it seems I should clarify something.
On the client side, we end up with a List of IParameters. This list is compiled by doing something of the sort:

```
IPamameter a = new Parameter { Value = IntVal };
IPamameter b = new Parameter { Value = BoolVal };

var listParams = new Parameters();
listParams.Add(a);
listParams.Add(b);
```

Now, I tried to use generics, but it did not quite work as the type for Parameter cannot really be generic (I think):

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int IntVal = 10;
        bool BoolVal = false;

        var a = new Parameter<int> { Value = IntVal };
        var b = new Parameter<bool> { Value = BoolVal };

        var listParams = new Parameters<T>();     // This does not work, it has to be an actual type, but I want all the params in the same list
        listParams.Add(a);
        listParams.Add(b);
    }
}

public class Parameter<T> : IParameter<T>
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string ValueType { get; set; }
    public T Value { get; set; }
}

public class Parameters<T> : List<IParameter<T>>
{

}

public interface IParameter<T>
{
    string Name { get; set; }
    string ValueType { get; set; }
    T Value { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Well, your starting point was to disable type safety, so you can assign any type to a variable, but somehow you want to have it. Doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: The simple answer to your question is "generics" but this usually leads you down a long winding road with somethign like this. It is important (for an answer) to understand how you *use* `IParameter` instances

Comment: What do you want to do with the parameters once you've added them to the list?

Comment: @Lee, I want to be able to modify parameters' value (which can be of different type for different parameters). But I would like the compiler to break if I assign a bool to a value that is supposed to be an int for instance

Comment: Can you set the value before you add them to the list? If you want to store heterogenous parameter values in the same list you will necessarily lose the ability to distinguish the different parameter types.

Comment: @Lee, nop, that is a variable that can be changed at runtime, but you know the type of each param value at compile time

Answer (score 1):

In order to store heterogenous parameters in the same list `IParameter` would need to stay non generic, and would have no type safety on the `Value` property:

```
public interface IParameter
{
    string Name{get;}
    string ValueType{get;}
    object Value{get;}
}
```

But, you could provide a generic implementation which enforces type safety on the `Value` and *explicitly* implements the Interfaces version, just returning the generic one.

```
public class Parameter<T> : IParameter
{
    public string Name{get;set;}
    public T Value {get;set;}
    public string ValueType {get => typeof(T).Name;}

    object IParameter.Value {get => this.Value;}
}
```

This would allow your client code to ensure the right types are set to the right parameters, for example:

```
var intParam = new Parameter<int>{Value = 10};
var strParam = new Parameter<string>{Value = "Hello World"};

var list = new List<IParameter>();
list.Add(intParam);
list.Add(strParam);
```

This would fail at compile time:

```
var badParam = new Parameter<int>{Value="Hello World"}; // Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'int'
```

Here is a live working example: https://dotnetfiddle.net/QSAUFR

The usefulness of this code is somewhat questionable. But it's perhaps a start. I fear you'll end up in generic hell quicker than you think!

Comment: Awesome! Thanks @Jamiec, that is very close. Now is there a way I could modify the list and get an error when using the from type. Say I was to do something like: list[0].Value = false; but expect an int, so the compiler complains

Comment: @progLearner nope, thats the problem. As soon as you stuff it in the list you've lost the compiletime type safety. The best I think you'll get is runtime safety by checking the type as part of a setter implemented from `IParameter`

Comment: +1 @Jamiec, damn, can you think of a better way to design such a system that requires to expose a bunch of parameters to a client (and keeps Type safety working). I am wondering how people usually deal with that. Loosing the type safety makes a system fragile as everything needs to be thoroughly tested (and will be hard to validate). I can't believe to be the only one with this problem.

Comment: @progLearner you're not but other systems handle this at runtime. Think about the SqlClient functionality. That has different "types" of parameter, but theyre all just object and if you pass an int where a string was expected it blows up at runtime.

Comment: Ouha! I am not familiar with Sql, but that sounds like a terrible design :-) How do people test their system in such a case? @Jamiec

Comment: Well, in that example the dev has written the db query and the client code. If the types dont match its the developers fault. A user cant impact that. I agree, if this is user input you need to be a lot more careful, but in terms of testing its just ensuring the runtime behaviour of an invalid input is what you/a user would expect. ie useful error messaging "You have passed a number for parameter abc, which expects a true or false".

Comment: Ok @Jamiec, so how would you handle the runtime error? Have the type checked in the setter and flag an error via popup when invalid? The expected behaviour of the system would be hard to test though!?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206453/discussion-between-jamiec-and-proglearner).